# How do I remove border from next and previous buttons after clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

I'm using the colorbox plugin for a photo gallery and it is working fine. However, once the next or prev buttons have been clicked a blue fuzzy border appears around the buttons. I don't know why this is happening - how do I make it go away?

[image]

Comment: looks like a browser thing - chrome does something like this for clicked anchor tags. You could try setting `outline: none;` on the elements.

Comment: `outline:none` will help

Comment: You can remove it but you shouldn't [http://www.outlinenone.com/](http://www.outlinenone.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I bet this happen because of focused element, so use: (button or whatever selector)

```
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue in IE.

Try setting the element to `border:none;`